# Find the natural numbers such that a number is a prime number.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, natural-numbers

Find the natural numbers $x$, $n$ such that $p = x^4+2^{4n+2}$ is prime number.

Comment: $x^4+4y^4$ factors.

Comment: Try not to just post questions, as people won't know where to start to be able to help you (and you will get downvotes and close votes, as has happened here). Try to explain what you have tried and where and why you got stuck/need help. It would also help if you said where you found this question (week X of course Y, where we covered topic Z).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $p$ as follows, $p=x^4+2^{4n+2}=x^4+4^{2n+1}=x^4+4\cdot 4^{2n}$. 
Now, $$x^4+4y^4=(x^2)^2+(2y^2)^2+2\cdot x^2\cdot 2y^2-4x^2y^2=(x^2+2y^2)^2-(2xy)^2\\=(x^2+2xy+2y^2)(x^2-2xy+2y^2)$$

We need $x^2-2xy+2y^2=1$, as this is the minimum factor, to make $p$ a prime. Here we have $y=4^n$. Someone already mentioned that $p=5$ is a solution. In fact it is the only solution.

Can you continue from here?